# Disable text "Settings" when click recent button android

Tags: android, button, menu, click

Why when I press this button, a pop up (with text Settings) is displayed in my app ?

[image]

**How can I remove it?**

Comment: remove overrided method from your code `onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu)` this will not display anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling this keys you need to override this method of the **Activity**

```
@Override    
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {    
    if (keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {    
        //return true if you want block button menu    
        return true;    
    }    
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```